# Rails : devise and best_in_place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller, best-in-place

I am using rails and devise for authentication(username - email -password) , I used best_in_place to edit another attributes for the user (age - ..) from another controller(profiles), but I when update the field attributes it is not saved even if I reload the page (It's not a jquery problem ) , so what should I do

Comment: Can you provide some more details

Answer (score 0):

Are you sanitizing Devise parameters before the update? In your ApplicationController add something like this:

```
before_filter :update_sanitized_params, if: :devise_controller?

def update_sanitized_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [:name, :avatar, :remote_avatar_url]
end
```

Another reason why your update action doesn't work, may be due that, you are not permiting additional fields in your ProfilesController.

```
def user_params
  accessible = [ :name, :email,:age... ] # extend with your own params
  params.require(:user).permit(accessible)
end
```

I hope that will help.